# How to categorize/name survey expenses in funding proposal budget section?

Tags: funding, research-proposal

I am writing a funding proposal. I am finding it difficult to fit the following expense into a suitable category. Can I title it as 'Survey Expense'? (note that there are no specific categories, but of course, I have to mention one for any expense I make). However, I suspect that this may put off the funding committee because they may argue that why don't I just have the survey form filled for free using my students' help, etc.

My proposed research will involve taking surveys from several people. For this reason, I would use paid services from websites such as SurveyMonkey and other resources. I also plan to give some 10 odd gift vouchers of $25 to survey participants to encourage them to take the survey.

Any guidance will be appreciated

Comment: Your questions seems to end in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited.

Comment: What kind of grant and funding committee? Does this committee evaluate survey research proposals on a regular basis or do Survey research themselves?

Comment: This is not survey research. The research is purely technical, but part of this is collection of data via surveys.